# Problem importing files in Django settings.py

Tags: django, configuration

I have a Django project which seemed to work pretty well with settings.py, which also imported a local_settings.py without problem.

I've now added the following lines at the end of the settings file :

```
try:
    from extras import *
except ImportError, e:
    print "import extras failed :: " + `e`
```

extras.py is a file of extra configuration information sitting in the same directory as settings.py and local_settings.py, however, I'm now getting :

```
import extras failed :: ImportError('Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.',)
```

This seems to be due to me trying to

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,UserManager
from django.db import models
```

in that extras.py file.

Anyone have any ideas?

cheers

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Typically, having a line like

```
from django.db import models
```

in `settings.py` *will* lead to a circular dependency. This causes an import error, which gets reported slightly differently in different versions of Django. For example, if I add that line to a working Django setup and invoke "manage.py shell", I get:

> Error: Can't find the file
>   'settings.py' in the directory
>   containing './manage.py'. It appears
>   you've customized things. You'll have
>   to run django-admin.py, passing it
>   your settings module. (If the file
>   settings.py does indeed exist, it's
>   causing an ImportError somehow.)

If I remove that line, everything's fine again.

The reason is that Django's model loading machinery (located in the `django.db.models` package) imports `settings.py`, reads its `INSTALLED_APPS` to see what apps should be installed, and then loads those apps. (You can confirm this by adding a print statement to `__init__.py` for one of your installed apps.)

If you try to import `django.db` stuff in `settings.py`, that will lead to a circular import dependency and an `ImportError`-related error message.

One workaround is to move the functionality which requires the problematic imports (and the imports themselves) to an app.

Comment: +1 The general rule is never to import anything from Django in settings.py.

Comment: See here, for details: http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html

Answer (score 3):

So how is `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` set in your environment?  It could be either that, or the result of the implicit import of settings which your other nested imports are causing while settings is being imported, a "circular dependency" that can have several nasty effects (though I don't believe it would have the specific one you're observing, so I lean towards the first hypothesis).